# Embed message discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Ive seen many discord embed codes like this:

(This is an old question and im new to coding so...)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

So, what i dont understand is what is the trigger? Like you're supposed to type .ping for pong right? so what do i type to get my bot type this embed?

Comment: Please look at some guides and tutorials before jumping into creating a discord bot. [This](https://discordjs.guide/) is a great guide to discord.js for beginners, and there are tons of video tutorials on youtube. It will save you a ton of time if you learn how to work with djs properly through these tutorials, so you don't have to get stuck on every step of creating a discord bot and ask question after question here. Asking this question is a lot like trying to skip the tutorial of a complex game you know nothing about; you'll get lost and confused when you could easily not be.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're sending your embed is(afaik) specific to version 13 of discord.js and you most likely haven't updated discord.js yet:

```js
channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

the version I am currently using is `12.5.3` .
Check your version of discord.js in `package.json` and if the version is not 13 or above, update or if you want to stick with version `12.5.3` try some of the methods below:

```js
channel.send( exampleEmbed );
```

Or like this:

```js
channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });
```

Sending the embed like this: "`{ embeds: [exampleEmbed] }`" makes discord think you are sending an empty message and therefore it doesn't send anything.

Comment: This is actually not entirely true. In discord.js V13 you **have to** use embeds as an array.

Comment: @ChristophBlüm Thanks. I edited my answer to take your comment into account.

Comment: @code_monkey023 My version is actually the same as you tho

Comment: @haojie Ok, if you want to stick with that version try `channel.send( exampleEmbed );` or `channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });`. If you want to use the code from your answer than you should update to version 13 of discord.js.

Comment: @haojie did you resolve your issue? If so then please mark the answer that helped you as correct.

Comment: @code_monkey023, I changed it to `channel.send( exampleEmbed );` , pretty much thats all i did, so now what do i do next?

Comment: @haojie Do you have your embed and send code in an event so it can trigger?

Comment: @haojie Like user15517071 writes in their answer I would suggest reading the guide you're following from the start so you dont end up with missing code like you are doing now. If you follow the guide 100% you will probably end up learning more as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code is meant to be inside an event handler (such as `on.message`). If that code is already inside an event handler (except for this `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');`, it should go at the top), and if it is still not sending, then you should change this line:

`channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });`

to

`message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no trigger in the code sample you provided. You need to have a listener for the message event or interactionCreate event to listen to traditional message-based commands and slash commands. You can pass in handlers into these listeners and respond to command usages.

Since it looks like you're [reading the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor), I would suggest [reading from the start](https://discordjs.guide/), where you would be introduced to how to handle messages first.

Answer (score 0):

To send it, just use a message event. Like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
const { channel, content } = msg;
if(msg.content === 'someCommand') {
const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
//setProperties...

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
})
client.login('[TOKEN_HERE'])
```

What's happening here is that the client is receiving a Message object when someone messages (`msg`). We then use the channel and content properties to evaluate the command, and send the embed if the command is correct. I took out the property settings to save space. You can add them back.

Comment: Well then the code you posted in your question isn’t the full code is it? Well just remove the top 2 lines. I just did those so that anyone who sees it can run it themselves.